# Null-check for inherited member in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, null-check

```js
abstract class Base {
  protected id: number | null = null;

  init(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  isIdSet(_ = this.id): _ is null | never {
    if (this.id === null) throw new Error(ERROR_NO_ID);
    else return false;
  }
}

class Foo extends Base {
  private fetch(id: number) { ... }
  
  get(): Observable<string> {
    if (this.isIdSet()) {
      return this.fetch(this.id); // TS2322: Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work because Typescript is unable to infer that `this.id` is not `null` from calling this function. You can use `if(this.id !== null)` instead. By definition, it will be a number if this resolves to `true`.

Comment: The idea was to put he null-check and `throw` into a function to get rid of duplicate `if` statements, but now I realize - I'd have `if` statement anyway, so no point in doing that.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could include that in the question, I added an answer to avoid having to use `if` statements whenever you have to access `id` from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The idea was to put he null-check and throw into a function to get rid of duplicate if statements`

You can do this in the base class with a custom getter that checks if `this.m_id` is defined and throws an error otherwise, essentially forcing the `init` method to be called before accessing `id`.

```
class Base {
    private m_id: number | null = null;

    protected get id(): number {
        if(this.m_id === null){
            throw new Error(`Id is not defined`);
        }
        return this.m_id;
    }

    public init(a_id: number): void {
        this.m_id = a_id;
    }
}


class Foo extends Base {
    private fetch(a_id: number): string {
        return a_id.toString();
    }

    public get(): string {
        return this.fetch(this.id);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoaXoAcBOAlgG5gAuSAtgPoEAmAXNAHYCuFARgntAD7MsgQ0ALz9BAbgwZsuPAHtywcrWgBzBKWh0AFAEpGrDlxTSZ2AgDNtAQlIALAhAB01OrrSYzX+-IDuzBH8AUTx5PG0AAwBJFUdmBWhaBAsCJgRaCN1JTy8AX1MvPA0WPCZoe0cXGlpsmXz0AtwWdhACYC0mAlJtMGqDNk48fWgiOToTHLMK51cVUV66Wux6+ql0UEgYADE5OWgEAA9yJloYeAgkDxl8YjIkCw1gOx6+-iMhxghSQiZVCa8sEVSCUygtaE5SHIAMrfVKqPRLLCrSY4ZqtdrqbrDL4-P5XAFAkHlBzOB6kJ7aaZONyI6ArIA)

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

```
abstract class Base {
  protected id: number | null = null;

  init(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  isIdSet(_ = this.id): asserts _ is number {
    if (this.id === null) throw new Error("ERROR_NO_ID");
  }
}

class Foo extends Base {
  private fetch(id: number) {}
  
  get() {
    this.isIdSet(this.id)
    return this.fetch(this.id);    
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=3&module=1&ts=4.7.4&ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIIAOUA9hDvDgCYICWdAXAgHYCuAtiDlAgA%20HTsmQIAvCLEBuQsSbtGEABTM2XXvwCUBBSQgALRmAB0zSUzpySAX3kkTASToBlHKoD6loyfN1tNjQwfggMbxMRLQEiEkcAMwQVXzMLCXTpZF0jSgB3Dhx8gFEoSigVACIigCVqgHlqzwA5Os8nABEK7RsEe3tCFGCEADEKCgQcAA9qdjoMbBC9EnJGADdgagR4j1hDNVYovihdfHsSBQBzDxUT-QQU8zAXd1UH5m07qA9OKHZ74zM2wgu2SAP83TiCAUfSAA)

Comment: Cool, never heard of Assertion Functions before, thanks! But unfortunately it doesn't work if you don't pass any argument to `isIdSet`.